# Struct array is printing garbage

Tags: c, arrays, struct, printf

I'm having an issue with printing out my struct array.  It is initialized like so:

`struct matrix tokens[nbrState][12];`

I then try to print it out with this code:

```
    printf("%d", tokens[0][0].state);
    for(int q = 0; q < nbrState; q++){
            for(int r = 0; r < 12; r++){
                    printf("%d", tokens[q][r].state);
            }
    }
```

How ever it just gives back

```
160833216083325909500442637211181530452359314445659095247095039827295039732859091035295039760059091066417471141950397584105931452485931525045870278695909110245869685280135590599950397784950397744593145248159314402459314316859095284905931452481590950044135934508013593144456590952470095039760058696836095039787258698266456147669503978565869965120593144552593143168419536358702168841950960596593143168950398056950398016593144552159315536059315450459095284905931445521015931545041048576587404166341899271605931553609503978729503978563593450804195363-1141298268758698266459314316800419611295039881600950398592587297673016950398176950397984091005908849605884315520000050-100950398592419
```

And I'm not sure why.  I'm also filling the array with values using this for loop.

```
while ( fscanf ( fp, "%d/%d%c", &index, &separateInt, &separateChar) == 3) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
            tokens[index][i].state = separateInt;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Well, your loop reads the `index` value from the input file. What makes you thing that it ever reads, say, `0` as index? I can't see the content of your file input file from here. Nobody can. How are we supposed to know which `index` values are there and which are not? Moreover, are you sure your initialization cycle even runs?

Answer (score 1):

You said

> It is initialized like so
>
> ```
> struct matrix tokens[nbrState][12];
> ```

But the above declaration does not *initialize* anything (unless your array is declared with static storage duration). A local array declared in this fashion will contain garbage at the beginning. That's apparently what you are printing.

If you want your array *initialized*, you have to initialize it yourself. For example, this declaration

```
struct matrix tokens[nbrState][12] = { 0 };
```

will initialize everything with zeros, assuming `nbrState` is a constant.

If `nbrState` is not a constant, then you will not be able to use a `= { ... }` initializer in the declaration. You will have to assign the initial values to your array elements manually, using a cycle or in some other way.

Comment: nbrState will stay constant once the program is run.  But can change depending on the input to the file.

Comment: I have a for loop to add values to the array. Then I try to print them.

Comment: @user2835532: Well, your loop reads the `index` value from the input file. What makes you thing that it ever reads, say, `0` as `index`? I can't see the content of your file input file from here. Nobody can. How are we supposed to know which `index` values are there and which are not? Moreover, are you sure your initialization cycle even runs?